# не срабатывает счетчик python

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Дан массив из строк, которые содержат смайлики, типа:

```
[':D',':~)',';~D',':)']
```

Нужно определить, сколько смайликов "с улыбкой"
Улыбкой считаются такие:

```
:) :D ;-D :~)
```

Алгоритм:

```
def count_smileys(arr):
    num = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if ")" or "D" in arr[i]:
            num =+ 1
    return num
```

Вот только, если подать аргументом функции строку с примером выше, мой num насчитает только 1, а не 4.
Причем все итерации проходят.

**Как оказалось,надо учитывать, что у смайлика должны быть:

одни из таких  "глаз" ;:
один из таких "носов"(или его отсутствие) -~ 
и одна из таких "улыбок" )D .**

Я пробовал через регулярные выражения:

```
return int(len(re.findall('[:;][-~]?[)D]', arr)))
```

но это так же не срабатывает, вываливаясь с ошибкой
expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: попробуйте запустить `print(")" or "D" in ":-)")` и посмотрите на результат - вы такой ожидали? ;-) После этого можно запустить `print(")" or "D")` ...

Comment: 1) ` expected string or bytes-like object` -- это потому что регулярки принимают в себя только строки или байтовые объекты, а вы передавали список 2) `int(len(...))` не нужно -- len и так возвращает int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
def count_smileys(arr):
    num = 0
    for x in arr:
        if ")" in x or "D" in x:
            num += 1
    return num


smileys = [':D', ':~)', ';~D', ':)']
print(count_smileys(smileys))  # 4
```

---

Вариант через регулярное выражение:

```
import re

def count_smileys(arr):
    num = 0
    for x in arr:
        if re.match('[;:][-~]?[)D]', x):
            num += 1
    return num

# Вариант в одну строку:
def count_smileys(arr):
    return sum(bool(re.match('[;:][-~]?[)D]', x)) for x in arr)


smileys = [':D', ':~)', ';~D', ':)', ':(', ':(D']
print(count_smileys(smileys))  # 4
```

Comment: это не срабатывает

Comment: А как вы использовали? Добавил в ответ пример использования

Comment: Использовал так же, проблема в том, что неправильно была понята задача, подробнее в комментарии у пользователя  @strawdog

Comment: @Павел, условия задачи должны быть описаны в вопросе, а не в комментарии, тем более в комментарии ответа :) Если вы что-то уточняли в комментарии, добавьте это в вопрос (кнопка `править`)

Comment: Добавил вариант через регулярное выражение

Comment: Да, вариант сработал, спасибо большое. Только интересно, почему вариант через len(re.findall) нерабочий.

Comment: @Павел, написал в комментарий к вопросу :)

Answer (score 4):

Думаю проблема все-таки в *"+="*

```
def count_smileys(arr):
    num = 0
    for i in arr:
        if ")" in i or "D" in i:
            num += 1
    return num
```

И, как уточнили, проблема также в строении логического выражения

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы понять что происходит можно воспользоваться модулем [dis (disassembler)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html):

```
In [367]: dis.dis('")" or "D" in ":-D"')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (')')
              2 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     10          # прыгаем на строку 10, т.к. первый аргумент в `OR` вернет истину
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 ('D')
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (':-D')
              8 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
        >>   10 RETURN_VALU
```

У вас в коде две ошибки - [вторую хорошо описал @TenDaI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/888961/211923), если ее исправить то ваш код будет всегда возвращать число строк в массиве, независимо от их содержимого

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал несколько по-другому:

```
a = [':D',':~)',';~D',':)']
res = (''.join(a)).count(')')+ (''.join(a)).count('D')
```

либо, ещё лучше:

```
smileys = [')', 'D']
for _ in smileys:
    res += (''.join(a)).count(_)

print(res)
```

При таком подходе не нужно лезть внутрь цикла, если придется менять критерии поиска.Единственный минус - такой подход не сработает для поиска смайлов типа ':)))'

Comment: Похоже, что этот алгоритм оптимальный, вот только, как оказалось,надо учитывать, что у смайлика должны быть:   одни из таких "глаз" [;:],один из таких "носов"(или его отсутствие) [-~] и одна из таких "улыбок" [)D]   . Я пробовал через регулярные выражения, return int(len(re.findall('[:;][-~]?[)D]', arr)))    но это так же не срабатывает, вываливаясь с ошибкой expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @Павел Ошибка вываливается потому, что регексп нужно натравливать на элемент списка, а не на весь список целиком. То есть, через for loop